# Unable to get the Service Name if the Service has spaces in between the name

Tags: batch-file

```
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    'wmic path win32_service where "name like "BMC Remedy Action%%"" get Name ^| findstr /V /R "^$"'
) do For /F "Delims=" %%B in ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B

:Sub
Set "Service=%*"
echo Service Name: %Service%
```

This gives me Empty result.

I cant use the below as i have more than 2 services with the name starting with BMC.

```
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    'wmic path win32_service where "name like "BMC%%"" get Name ^| findstr /V /R "^$"'
) do For /F "Delims=" %%B in ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B

:Sub
Set "Service=%*"
echo Service Name: %Service%
```

Help Please!

Comment: If you know the name of the service you are looking for then why are you using `Like` and why not just set the name directly.  Also the second `For` loop is supposed to be instead of the piped `FindStr`; Choose one or the other.

Comment: `where "name like 'BMC Remedy Action%%'" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues.1) You are using two double quotes in the FOR /F expression 2) You are trying to match the DisplayName of the service instead of the name.

Try like this:

```
For /F "useback Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    `wmic path win32_service where 'DisplayName like "BMC Remedy Action%%"' get Name ^| findstr /V /R "^$"`
) do For /F "Delims=" %%B in ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
```

Comment: Right. Im using 2 double quotes in the For expression :) Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd probably do it, (I have changed `Name` to `DisplayName` because it seems likely that you're using the wrong one).

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC Service Where (DisplayName Like 'BMC Remedy Action%%') Get Name"'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Set "Service=%%B"
Echo(%Service%
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF
```

If you do need to get rid of padded whitespace from the end of the string:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    '"WMIC Service Where (DisplayName Like 'BMC Remedy Action%%') Get Name"'
) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :Sub %%B
Echo("%Service%"
Timeout -1
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
Set "Service=%*"
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: '"WMIC Service (Where Name Like '%%Remedy%%') Get Name"', here it is taking %%R as a variable and not as %%Remedy%%

Comment: I update that code some time ago, when I edited the `Name` to `DisplayName`, much in the same way as the answer you've accepted. I have since fixed my error with the positioning of my parenthesis though.